# IE7 Can't render link (with background transparent) over a text?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

This is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/ZXzJ2/1/) :

## HTML :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="myBox">My Text</div>        
    <a class="myLink" href="http://www.google.com">&nbsp;</a>       
</div>    ​
```

## CSS :

```
.container
{
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}

.myBox
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:90;
    background-color:#ff0000;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;    
}

.myLink
{
    text-decoration:none; 
    display:block; 
    position:absolute; 
    width:50px; 
    height:50px; 
    top:0px; 
    left:0px; 
    z-index:100;
}​
```

on IE7, the link over "My text" doesnt work as link. If, on `myLink` I put a background-color, it works as well.

Am I on drugs or it is a normal behaviour? And how can I fix this with a transparent background?

Comment: Any specific reason why you're doing it that way? Think it's intended behavior, as "myLink" is essentially empty.

Comment: I'm linking a "zone" over an image...

Comment: +1 @Mario You should be using an image map.

Comment: image map have some troubles on mobile...

Comment: also, "link" get more points with SEO...

Comment: An essentially empty link might actually be worse SEO wise I'd assume.

Comment: There is a &nbsp; , not really empty! I'd like to know this :)

Comment: It's empty after removing whitespaces, so I wouldn't do it that way. If it's meant to be an image map, how about using a image showing either that part of the image map (might allow some nice mouse hover feedback as well) or just use a transparent 1px image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add these lines to `.myLink`:

```
background-color:#ff0000;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
```

**EDIT**

If there will be only an image in `.myBox`, `.myLink` will work as expected, if the image is added as a background image to `.myBox`.

Comment: Using filters is no permanent solution, because Microsoft is going to drop support for them with IE10.

Comment: I think you're a bit biased there, plus I don't really understand that attitude (nothing personal). If you're adding extra code for the page to work in a specific product line (here: IE), I'd especially try to ensure the latest version works as well (more so than any other older version), no matter how many issues are fixed or still open: It's the latest version and it's market share will definitely rise - not fall. Nothing bad in dropping IE6 or even IE7 nowadays, but don't ignore IE9 or IE10. Not sure how IE10 handles "empty" links though, so in case the whole topic doesn't apply to IE10...

Comment: @Mario I`m sorry, I haven't meant to be biased in any way. However, this OP's problem bothers also IE9, and can be fixed in both ways I've answered. I'm not just going to guess the fix for IE10, since I haven't tested it, and maybe it won't even have the issue. If it has, fixes hardly are not competitive with older IEs.

Comment: No problem. Just sounded a bit like "IE10 will be crap anyway, so just ignore it".