# Internet Explorer 9 and below z-index text cursor bug

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I recently discovered an odd bug in ie 9, 8 and 7 (See http://jsfiddle.net/global_1981/rrKaV/1/)

It doesn't respect the cursor:pointer css rule for an absolutely positioned anchor element when it is layered over a block element that has text.

The text becomes selectable, instead of retaining the cursor:pointer.

To fix this, you cannot have the anchor element have a background-color set to transparent. Instead it has to be set to a solid color, or in my case I needed to see the text below, so I set the background-image to a non-existing image.

Has anybody come across this bug or have a better fix?

Comment: Quite similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11083249/ie7-cant-render-link-with-background-transparent-over-a-text/11085782#11085782

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply puting div inside your absolutely positioned div?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="fix">
        <div class="txt">Some text</div>
    <div>
    <a class="lnk" href="#"></a>
</div>

<div class="container ieworks">
    <div class="txt">Some text</div>
    <a class="lnk" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  position:relative; z-index:1; width:100px; height:20px; background-color:red;
}
.fix {
position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; cursor:pointer;
}

.txt {
  color:white;
}
.lnk {
      position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; z-index:3;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, unfortunately that solution wouldn't work for the specific use case I had when I came across this issue - as the container div (.container) needed to get its width from its child div with the text (.txt). Shame that you cant even trust the most recent versions of IE to behave constituently with the other more competent browsers.