# Empty anchor tag inside absolute positioned div IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, anchor, css-position

I have searched and searched and tried many of options to fix this "bug", and I cannot get it to work. I have a div that has a background image that is half-way hidden behind the wrapper. On hover, it animates towards the top. The link is inside an absolute positioned div, and has no text. On IE there is no "pointer", therefore making the link un-clickable. This works in Chrome/FF.

I've tried:

1. border-right 1px transparent (this i actually can get a "pointer"
   on the far right, but it's so small
2. background:
       url(/images/transparent.gif) 0 0 repeat; (yes i made a 1x1px trans
       image)
3. put another div inside the anchor that has the background
       image
4. z-index: 0 or 1 or 2

I would like the CSS/HTML fix for this, not javascript. Thanks so much!

CSS

```
#wrapper
{
width: 950px;
margin: 60px auto 40px;
background-color: #fff;
position:relative;
}

.login-btn
{
background: url(/images/btn-sprite.png) no-repeat 0 -48px;
height: 34px;
width: 98px;
}

#login-btn
{
position:absolute;
top:-15px;
right:20px;
z-index:-1;
}

#login-btn a
{
display:block; 
width: inherit; 
height: inherit; 
background-image: url(/images/transparent.gif) 0 0 repeat; 
}
```

HTML

```
    <div id="wrapper" class="round">
        <div id="login-btn" class="login-btn">
            <a href="#">
            </a>
        </div>
    .....
    .....
```

Comment: didn't understood anything.

Comment: Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11085782/1169519

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code, i am attaching the image also please copy to youe image folder and test. i checked in ie8 and ie7 it is working fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
#wrapper {
    width: 950px;
    height:450px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    border:#F33 solid thin;
    position:relative;
}

#login-btn {
    height: 33px;
    width: 145px;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:5px;
}
#login-btn a:link, #login-btn a:visited {
    background:url(images/btn-sprite.png) top left no-repeat;
    height: 33px;
    width: 145px;
    display:block;
}

#login-btn a:hover {
    background:url(images/btn-sprite.png) bottom left no-repeat;
    height: 33px;
    width: 145px;
    display:block;
    cursor:pointer;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="login-btn">
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: this is a sprite image]

Comment: I do not think you read my post properly. I do not have a button that changes styles, I have a button that animates (eases). Second thing is I have the button hidden half-way underneath the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out. in IE, you cannot have an anchor w/ a negative z-index, b/c it hides it behind the body or whatever, and the event doesn't get passed through. basically what I ended up doing is placing the anchor around the div (login-btn), and giving the div a z-index of -1, therefore relieving the z-index on the anchor

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper" class="round">
<a href="#" id="login-btn">
    <div class="login-btn">
    </div>
</a>
....
....
```

CSS

```
#wrapper
{
  width: 950px;
  margin: 60px auto 40px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position:relative;
}

.login-btn
{
  background: url(/images/btn-sprite.png) no-repeat 0 -48px;
  height: 34px;
  width: 98px;
}

a#login-btn
{
  display:block; 
  height: 34px;
  width: 98px;
  position:absolute;
  top:-15px;
  right:20px;
}

a#login-btn div
{
  z-index: -1;
  position:relative;   
}
```